# Proving a bipartite graph is not planar

Tags: graph-theory, network

I have drawn the bipartite graph K3,3. And I need to prove this graph isn't planar. I used contradiction, assuming it was planar, using Eulers formula to prove it wasn't planar.

I concluded my graph should have 5 faces according to Eulers formula, I then labeled faces on my graph to conlcude there are >5 faces in this graph, and it is clearly not planar.

Is this sufficient enough to prove my graph is not planar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the key observation: if a planar bipartite graph has at least one cycle, every face has at least four edges. Counting each edge by its incident faces shows that $4f \le 2m$. This inequality combined with Euler's formula gives $4 = 2n - 2m + 2f \le 2n - m$. However, $K_{3,3}$ has $n=6$ and $m=9$, and so it is not planar.

Answer (score 0):

You should first find the amount of vertices, edges, and faces in your graph. Then use euler's formula and if you do not get 2, the graph is not planar.

Comment: Yes I used eulers formula to conclude I 'should' have 5 faces in my graph, according to my edges and vertices in the graph - what I was wondering was, is it conclusive enough to say I have counted more than 5 faces in my graph after using eulers.